# React terminal many assets rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Can someone help me with Issue in my react. After I create new react app and then i start npm start i have this in my terminal. I dont know why but sometimes my app stop working because loader.

```
assets by path static/ 1.52 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.51 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.88 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
  asset static/media/logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg 2.57 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 546 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 31.4 KiB 16 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.38 MiB 95 modules
modules by path ./src/ 18.1 KiB
  modules by path ./src/*.css 8.82 KiB
    ./src/index.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 1.37 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css 2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/*.js 5.65 KiB
    ./src/index.js 1.78 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/App.js 2.49 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/reportWebVitals.js 1.38 KiB [built] [code generated]`enter code here`
  ./src/logo.svg 3.61 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.65.0 compiled successfully in 1182`enter code here`9 ms
```

Comment: This is just webpack telling you which files have been created.